# Multiple Slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I am learning Power Bi and was looking a report where multiple slicer having used in single Rectangle shapes. I need to know how can we add multiple slicer in single rectangle like this in image.

[image]

here in the  image multiple slicer or filter has been used. Please help me to understand the concept of it. how we can build something like this in Power Bi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple slicers on top of a rectangle shape and then group them all together by selecting all the objects and right-clicking them and choosing Group. Then you can move them as a single object.

[image: Group Together]